# Change Privacy Policy URL in play.google.com/apps/publish/

Tags: android, google-play-services, privacy

[image]
I entered the wrong URL in Privacy Policy URL box and published the app in alpha release. App is now  *Pending publication* status.

There is no option to change Privacy Policy URL now.

Comment: Are you changing URL from store presence> store listing?

Comment: @AkhileshPatil thanks, store listing had the option to change url. make it as answer i will accept.

Comment: glad to know your task completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2020**

Privacy Policy is moved to

> Store presence > App Content

[image]

**Old**

You change Privacy Policy URL from `Store Presence>Store Listing`

Goto bottom of the page and change the URL

Comment: I don't see the option to change Privacy Policy URL at the bottom or anywhere on the page. Is this answer still valid?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Do you have any knowledge, when the new URL will be published on PlayStore? I have updated mine over 24h ago and PlayStore still present the old URL :(

Answer (score 3):

December 2020, It has been moved to *Policy -> App content*

[image]

Comment: It really moves a lot :-)

Comment: As of September 2023, it is now in __"Policy and programs -> App content"__ section.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 14, 2020, you can find it at ***store presence -> app content***