# Modify Privacy Policy URL in the recent Playstore console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to change the Privacy Policy URL of my published Playstore App. But I cannot locate the Privacy Policy URL section that used to be in App > Store Presence > Store Listing.

There's an old answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651117/3144836 that is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Store presence -> App Content

Privacy policy can be changed from there.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFORA.png)

**Update :-**

Privacy Policy has been moved to

> App Content -> Privacy Policy

Comment: Do you know any estimated time or how long does it take for policy link to be show/updated in store listing? I happen to update the information and figured it does not immediately show in store listing. Should I make another realease?

Comment: It is showing now. It takes something between 10-60 minutes, I guess it is all cache pages being updated.

Comment: in my case it was between 5 - 30 minutes before i haven't noticed how long now it takes in updated version i will update the answer once i have verified how much time it takes. Thank you for the suggestion.